# How to start computation when entire UI is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the simplest case -- show progress bar, start computation, close progress bar.

With such html piece:

```
<p id="hello" style="display:none">HELLO WORLD</p>
```

To my surprise this does not work:

```
function foo()
{
    var hello = $('#hello');
    hello.html(new Date().getTime());
    hello.show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        var big = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<10000000;++i)
            if (Math.sqrt(i)>Math.cos(i)) // just to keep CPU busy
                big = i;
        console.log(i);
    },0);

}

$(window).load(function () 
{
    foo();
});
```

And using jQuery `promise` does not help as well:

```
hello.show().promise().done(function(){...
```

In both cases the element is shown (visually) at the same time as you have the output in console.

I wrote visually, because internally the element can be reported as already shown, but what user sees counts.

Comment: $(document).ready() or $(body).on('load', function() {...})???

Comment: This question is very unclear. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: a plnkr would be preferable...

Comment: @FishBasketGordo, quote "show progress bar, start computation, close progress bar."

Comment: @Fals, I don't understand what you asking.

Comment: Do you have control on the code which does the computation ? If yes, in the beginning of starting computation start the progress bar and at the end close it.

I cant see the code above which does the computation

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq, I have the control. In the above example the for-loop does the computation. And no -- it does not work that way, because the browser won't update the UI until the computation is done.

Comment: Wild assumption: the timeout is directly called internally as you provide `0`. Using `requestAnimationFrame` instead probably waits for the UI thread to update first.

Comment: @LJ_1102, I wrote `0` because I found such code as solution to similar problem. Ok, about the method you mention, like that `hello.show(); requestAnimationFrame(function(){...`. It does not work.

Comment: Too bad. As stated it was only an assumption. Anyway you should avoid locking the main thread with computations as the user experience is bad and you cant know when the browser stops your script as being unresponsive. This is why you should split your computations over several requestAnimationFrame calls. Not a solution to your question but a better way that works.

Comment: @LJ_1102, you are right, and this is what I would like to learn. For now with just single UI update -- on start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your code for computing in separate javascript function, even its linear it wont wait for computing to get finished in javascript and move to next line immediately. I have put a wait before hiding the progress bar because you need to have it available for atleast a second.

```
function startComputing(){
        var big = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<10000000;++i)
            if (Math.sqrt(i)>Math.cos(i)) // just to keep CPU busy
                big = i;
        console.log(i);
}

function foo()
{
    var hello = $('#hello');
    hello.html(new Date().getTime());
    hello.show();
    setTimeout(function(){startComputing();},500);
    setTimeout(function(){hello.hide()},1000);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote in comment, this does not work, you have linear workflow, and changing UI despite is before computation in code, is done **after** computation is finished.

Comment: Does this work for you or I am still not able to understand what is required ?

Comment: The point is to show the "hello" BEFORE the computation starts (think of it as progress bar). With your code it looks like this -- screen is empty, computation starts (which takes a long time and user has no clue what is going on), hello show up, the result of computation is shown, after 1 second "hello" disappears.

Comment: The updated answer is ugly but before starting the computation we are allowing DOM to update the visibility of hello element. If this is even is not working for you you can increase the time for setTimeout for startComputing to 1 second.

Comment: Oddly you hit the nail in the head. `0` for timeout does nothing really, but `1` (which could be read "quickly as possible, but not now") does the trick. Please change "500" to "1", for future reference.